# How to get correct sum of salaries

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name >
      <firstName>Arshad </firstName>
      <lastName lang="EN"> khan </lastName>
    </name>
    <dateOfBirth>
      <day>Monday</day>
      <month>June</month>
      <year>1978</year>
    </dateOfBirth>
    <address>
      <address1>7 pickering road </address1>
      <address2> barking Essex</address2>
      <city> London </city>
    </address>
    <department>
      computer Science
    </department>
    <salary> 10000 
    </salary>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>
      <firstName> khalid </firstName>
      <lastName> Niazi</lastName>
    </name> 
    <salary>3000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

In this XML document I am trying to get `sum()` of all the salaries.

I tried using XSLT but it is returning 10000 and 3000 but I need total of all the employee salaries. I need total of salaries in form of 10000 + 3000 or what ever salaries of all employee just show total of salaries.

XSLT that is currently calculating the sum of all the salaries:

```
<xsl:template match="employees/employee">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(salary)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The template you showed in the original question:

```
<xsl:template match="employees/employee">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(salary)" />
</xsl:template>
```

will fire once for *each* `employee` element, and will print out the sum of all the `salary` elements inside that particular `employee` (there is only one `salary` in each, so the result of the `sum` will be just the value of that single element).  If you want the total sum of all the salaries of all employees then instead you want a template that matches the next level up:

```
<xsl:template match="employees">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(employee/salary)" />
</xsl:template>
```